# @computed property with this.args in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Some of codes contains `@computed("args.param")` property behind of getters in ember.js.
But I can use `this.args.param` in the getters without `@computed("args.param")`, and there is no problem in it.
What's the differece between `@computed("args.param")` using and not using?

between

```
  @computed('args.date')
  get currentMonth() {
    return moment(this.args.date, 'YYYY-MM').startOf('month');
  }
```

and

```
  get currentMonth() {
    return moment(this.args.date, 'YYYY-MM').startOf('month');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@computed`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@ember%2Fobject/computed) *may* be needed if you need compatibility with pre-[`@tracked`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@glimmer%2Ftracking/tracked) code.

If your project is using ember-source@3.13+, then it supports [`@tracked`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@glimmer%2Ftracking/tracked), and [`@computed`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@ember%2Fobject/computed) isn't needed at all. You can delete all of those decorators.

A bit of a caveat tho: if you have any getters that computeds may depend on, you would then need to add [`@dependentKeyCompat`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcompat/dependentKeyCompat) to those getters -- but I encourage the removal of all [`@computed`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@ember%2Fobject/computed)s

Comment: Can you explain more about `@dependentKeyCompat `?

Comment: Not as well as the docs can: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcompat/dependentKeyCompat